# Getting User Utterance as Text in Amazon Sumerian

Tags: amazon-sumerian

I have a Sumerian Host that acts basically as a front-end for a Lex chatbot.

However, in some cases, I need to to some processing based on the actual user utterance (that is, the text of what the user says). Is there a way I can use "Send Audio to Lex" action (or a different one) to get a text version of the user audio (so, to perform speech-to-text)?